# Laravel: FatalErrorException

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, fatal-error

I have problem with like system. If i click on like button it throws me an error: 
**FatalErrorException in PostController.php line 80:

  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Like' not found**

Line 80 in my post Controller is:

```
$like = new Like();
```

This is my full function:

```
  public function postLikePost(Request $request){
  $post_id = $request['postId'];
  $is_like = $request['isLike'] === 'true' ? true : false;
  $update = false;
  $post = Post::find($post_id);
  if(!$post){
    return null;
  }
  $user = Auth::user();

  $like = $user->likes()->where('post_id', $post_id)->first();
  if($like){
    $already_like = $like->like;
    $update = true;
    if($already_like == $is_like){
      $like->delete();
      return null;
    }
  } else{
    $like = new Like();
  }
  $like->like = $is_like;
  $like->user_id = $user->id;
  $like->post_id = $post->id;


  if($update){
    $like->update();
  }else{
    $like->save();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Do you know where is the problem? Thank you.
(I am using Laravel v5.2.39)

Comment: You need to import it at the top.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? The exception is very clear about what the problem is.

Comment: Where is the file containing the `Like` class relative to your project root? Also, what does the `namespace` line toward the top of that file say?

Comment: Thank you guys. I have tried almost everything(check relationships, ajax, routes, controller), but I have forgot to use App\Like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `use Your_Namespace\Like;` before class statement.

**In controller:-**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use DB;

use App\Like; // use Your_Namespace\Like; add this line here
```

OR you can directly write,

```
$like = new \App\Like(); // new \Your_Namespace\Like();
```

Please refer [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers).

By default `Your_Namespace` is `App`.

You can change namespace by below command:-

```
php artisan app:name Your_Namespace
```

Comment: Yes, i forgot to import it. Thank you very much, I hate this type of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import it.

Add `use App\Like;` to the top of PostController.php
(Assuming it's in the App namespace)

Comment: How do you know it's in the `App` namespace?

Comment: Right. I don't. I was just adding that 'assumption' to the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is App namespace. Thank you.